# php deserialize doesnt deserialize the full json and no error messages

Tags: php, symfony, oop, error-handling, deserialization

I made a class based on the JSON i get from a API. The API is written in c# so i cant copy from that class because its mostly lists.

This is how the JSON looks like.

```
    {"Columns":[{"ColumnNumber":0,"ColumnName":"NAME","DataType":"string"},{"ColumnNumber":1,"ColumnName":"PK_R_RELATION","DataType":"int"}]}
```

This is a var_dump() from my class.

```
object(Table)#1250 (2) {
  ["Columns":"Table":private]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(Column)#1221 (0) {
      ["ColumnNumber":"Column":private]=>
      uninitialized(int)
      ["ColumnName":"Column":private]=>
      uninitialized(string)
      ["DataType":"Column":private]=>
      uninitialized(string)
    }
  }
```

It is practicly the same but the (Symfony serializer) deserializer doesn't put data in the class. When I make the "object(Column)#1221" as seen in the second picture a array it all works but its not desired that way. I think the problem has something to do with my normalizer/extractor but im not sure.

```
$encoder = [new JsonEncoder()];
$extractor = new PropertyInfoExtractor([], [new PhpDocExtractor(), new ReflectionExtractor()]);
$normalizer = [new ArrayDenormalizer(), new ObjectNormalizer(null, null, null, $extractor)];
$this->serializer = new Serializer($normalizer, $encoder);

public static function deserialize($data, string $type)
    {
        return JsonHelper::getInstance()->serializer->deserialize($data, $type, self::format);
    }
```

Is there any way to troubleshoot or get a error message from the deserialize method?

Comment: You can always debug the source code. Do some dumps throughout the process and find out where this data gets lost. Maybe that will give you the idea what could be done to amend the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you annotate your PHP `Table` class ?
Tried your exemple with :

```
class Table
{

    /**
     * @var Column[]
     */
    private array $Columns;

    /**
     * @return Column[]
     */
    public function getColumns(): array
    {
        return $this->Columns;
    }

    /**
     * @param Column[] $Columns
     */
    public function setColumns(array $Columns): void
    {
        $this->Columns = $Columns;
    }
}
```

```
class Column
{
    private $ColumnNumber;
    private $ColumnName;
    private $DataType;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getColumnNumber()
    {
        return $this->ColumnNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $ColumnNumber
     */
    public function setColumnNumber($ColumnNumber): void
    {
        $this->ColumnNumber = $ColumnNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getColumnName()
    {
        return $this->ColumnName;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $ColumnName
     */
    public function setColumnName($ColumnName): void
    {
        $this->ColumnName = $ColumnName;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getDataType()
    {
        return $this->DataType;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $DataType
     */
    public function setDataType($DataType): void
    {
        $this->DataType = $DataType;
    }


}
```

```
public function testDeserialize(): Table {
    $json = '{"Columns":[{"ColumnNumber":0,"ColumnName":"NAME","DataType":"string"},{"ColumnNumber":1,"ColumnName":"PK_R_RELATION","DataType":"int"}]}';
    $encoder = [new JsonEncoder()];
    $extractor = new PropertyInfoExtractor([], [new PhpDocExtractor(), new ReflectionExtractor()]);
    $normalizer = [new ArrayDenormalizer(), new ObjectNormalizer(null, null, null, $extractor)];
    $serializer = new Serializer($normalizer, $encoder);
   return $serializer->deserialize($json,Table::class,'json');
}
```

and I got that result :

```
App\Serialize\Table {#6385 ▼
  -Columns: array:2 [▼
    0 => App\Serialize\Column {#3274 ▼
      -ColumnNumber: 0
      -ColumnName: "NAME"
      -DataType: "string"
    }
    1 => App\Serialize\Column {#666 ▼
      -ColumnNumber: 1
      -ColumnName: "PK_R_RELATION"
      -DataType: "int"
    }
  ]
}
```

The thing is the deserializer doesn't know what type of data is within the array. Using that extractor it will read the annotations and will have all the informations to get the job done.